# Equivalent of C# lock in Java?

Tags: c#, java, multithreading

Equivalent of C# lock in Java?

For example:

```
public int Next() {
  lock (this) {
    return NextUnsynchronized();
  }
}
```

How do I port this C# method to Java?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
public int Next() {
    synchronized (this) {
        return NextUnsynchronized();
    }
}
```

That's it. And the next code is better.

```
public synchronized int Next() {
    return NextUnsynchronized();
}
```

Comment: synchronized  method seems a nice solution!

Comment: @user3111311 please choose answer >o<

Comment: @Lee you must post comments related to answer/question. Don't use comments in such way;

Answer (score 0):

```
java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock    
lock.lock();

    int newCount = ++count;
    lock.unlock();
```

Comment: Obviously not needed in your example, but in the general case, you should write try {...} finally {lock.unlock();}